# Does this double sum $\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m+n+mn}{2^m(2^m+2^n)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m+n+mn}{2^m(2^m+2^n)}$$
I have no experience evaluating double sums, but what intuition I have about single sums suggests to me that this series should converge. However, Mathematica fails to evaluate the sum and WolframAlpha tells me the series [diverges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[Sum[%28m%2Bn%2Bmn%29%2F%282%5Em%282%5Em%2B2%5En%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2CInfinity%7D]%2C%7Bm%2C0%2CInfinity%7D]).

I'm wondering if the averaging technique used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847928/i-need-help-with-a-double-sum) might yield something useful, but I don't if I'm adapting it properly. If $S$ denotes my sum, then
$$2S=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m+n+mn}{2^{m+n}}$$
which I'm told also [diverges](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[Sum[%28m%2Bn%2Bmn%29%2F%282%5Em%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2CInfinity%7D]%2C%7Bm%2C0%2CInfinity%7D]). I don't think this method will work since I can't split the numerator into a product $a_mb_n$.

Comment: some brute force testing suggested that the series does indeed converge: to 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial series is **convergent**: you may consider partial sums to manipulate terms as you did, and since $$\displaystyle n+m+mn\leq 3(m+1)(n+1), \quad n\geq0,\,m\geq0,$$ you obtain
$$
0<2S=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m+n+mn}{2^{m+n}}\leq\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3(m+1)(n+1)}{2^{m+n}}=3\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)^2=48.
$$

Comment: Don't we have to worry about when $m=0$ or $n=0$ where $m+n+mn\ge 3mn$? It's not too hard, but not really trivial. In fact, the original sum is actually $12$.

Comment: @robjohn I will edit, thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Just curious as to the relevance of the $3$.  Do we not have $n+m+nm\le (n+1)(m+1)=n+m+nm+1$?

Comment: @Dr.MV Sure. But I did not see it first... Then I didn't want to change it, since it was about convergence :) Thanks.

Comment: No worry.  Just curious.

Answer (score 14):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{m+n+mn}{2^{m+n}}
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(m+1)(n+1)}{2^{m+n}}
-\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{m+n}}\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)^2
-\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\right)^2\\[6pt]
&=12
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I always seem to forget that I can add and subtract... Thanks!

Comment: it should be $6$ not $12$

Comment: @OussamaBoussif robjohn was merely evaluating $2S$, not $S$.

Comment: Ah yes I didn't see that oops ^^

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if your goal is specifically evaluating the double sum or just showing it converges (per your intuition), but we can show the sum converges as follows:

\begin{align}
 \sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{m+n+mn}{2^m(2^m+2^n)}&\leq\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{2^m}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{m+n+mn}{2^n}\right]\\
&\leq\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left[\frac{m}{2^{m-1}}+\frac{C}{2^m}+\frac{mC}{2^m}\right],
\end{align}

where $C$ denotes the convergent sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n/2^n$. The right-hand side is easily evaluated to give a finite number, hence the original sum converges.

Comment: I'm concerned with finding out if WA's conclusion is mistaken, so just telling whether or not the sum converges would suffice. Judging by robjohn's answer, finding the actual sum is a good exercise.

Answer (score 3):

Under assumption that it does converge, you can renumber the series. Imagine a $nm$ plane, and sample the points diagonally. In other words, say $k=m+n$ and write

$$2S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{n=0}^k (k+kn-n^2)$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k} \left(k(k+1)+k\frac{k(k+1)}{2}-\frac{k(k+1)
(2k+1)}{6}\right)$$
$$=\frac16\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k} k(k+1)(k+5)$$
This is a convergent series: polynomial times a geometric progression has the same radius of convergence as the geometric series (for 1/2 in this case) and it can be evaluated by taking the derivative of the generating funcion $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ and then setting $x=1/2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$S\le\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{m+n+mn}{2^m 2^n}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{m}{2^m} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}+\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^m} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}+\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{m}{2^m} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}< \infty.$$

Comment: When $m=0$ or $n=0$ you have $mn=0$ and not **necessarily** $m+n+mn \leq 3mn$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yes, you're right! I typed that in a hurry. Still,  I think the best way to show it is to remove $2^m$ from the brackets.