# How do we approach this summation question?

Tags: summation

How do we find the following sum---

$\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^\infty \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{mn^2}{2^n(n2^m+m2^n)}$

Comment: It was asked here with a 3 : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796089/double-sum-trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This problem is just a slight variant of the [Putnam 1999 A4](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/1999.pdf) problem. You can see the solution [here:](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/1999s.pdf)